# Prove that $\frac{bc}{a^2+bc}+\frac{ca}{b^2+ca}+\frac{ab}{c^2+ab}\le{\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}}$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method, tangent-line-method

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers. Prove that

$\frac{bc}{a^2+bc}+\frac{ca}{b^2+ca}+\frac{ab}{c^2+ab}\le{\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}}$.

I have no idea how to solve this question.

Comment: First use LCM for numerator

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg , do not make superficial edits to gain tag points, nor to bump a question you answered more than a year and a half-ago.  Editing a question in order to get more votes on tags that did not, and do not, apply, is gaming the system.

Answer (score 3):

This proof appears to be a bit complex.

$ \sum _{ cyc }^{ {  } }f(a,b,c)=f(a,b,c)+f(b,c,a)+f(c,a,b)$

Note that the $(LHS)\le \sum _{ cyc }^{ {  } } \frac { (\frac { b+c }{ 2 } )^{ 2 } }{ a^{ 2 }+(\frac { b+c }{ 2 } )^{ 2 } } (\because AM-GM)$

WLOG $a+b+c=3$

Since $\sum _{ cyc }^{  }{ \frac { 3-3a }{ 2 }  } =0$, we can conclude that we need to show  $\frac { (\frac { b+c }{ 2 } )^{ 2 } }{ a^{ 2 }+(\frac { b+c }{ 2 } )^{ 2 } } \le \frac { a }{ b+c } +\frac { 3-3a }{ 2 }= \frac { a }{ 3-a } +\frac { 3-3a }{ 2 } $

Note that $\frac { (\frac { b+c }{ 2 } )^{ 2 } }{ a^{ 2 }+(\frac { b+c }{ 2 } )^{ 2 } } =\frac { { (3-a) }^{ 2 } }{ 4a^{ 2 }+(3-a)^{ 2 } } \le \frac { a }{ 3-a } +\frac { 3-3a }{ 2 } \Leftrightarrow \frac { { (3-a) }^{ 2 } }{ 4a^{ 2 }+(3-a)^{ 2 } } \le \frac { 2a+(a-3)(3a-3) }{ 2(3-a) }$

This indicates 
$2(3-a)^{ 3 }\le (3a^{ 2 }-10a+9)(5a^{ 2 }-6a+9)\Leftrightarrow 15a^{ 4 }-68a^{ 3 }+132a^{ 2 }-144a+81+2(a-3)^{ 3 }\ge 0\\ \Leftrightarrow 15a^{ 4 }-66a^{ 3 }+114a^{ 2 }-90a+27\ge 0\Leftrightarrow 3(a-1)^{ 2 }(5a^{ 2 }-12a+9)\ge 0$

However, since $5a^{ 2 }-12a+9\ge 0$, our inequality is proven.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum \left(\frac{a}{b+c} - \frac{ab}{c^2+ab}\right) = (a^3+b^3+c^3+abc) \sum {\frac {ca \left( {b}^{2}+{c}^{2} \right)  \left( a-b \right) ^{2}}{\displaystyle \prod (a+b)(a^2+bc)}} \geqslant 0.$$

Answer (score -1):

We can use SOS here.
$\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{b+c}-\frac{bc}{a^2+bc}\right)=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^3+abc-b^2c-bc^2}{(b+c)(a^2+bc)}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^3-abc+2abc-b^2c-bc^2}{(b+c)(a^2+bc)}=$
$=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{2a(a^2-bc)+2bc(2a-b-c)}{(b+c)(a^2+bc)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)(a^2+ac+2bc)-(c-a)(a^2+ab+2bc)}{(b+c)(a^2+bc)}=$
$=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)\left(\frac{a^2+ac+2bc}{(b+c)(a^2+bc)}-\frac{b^2+bc+2ac}{(a+c)(b^2+ac)}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2(a^2b^2+(a^3-a^2b-ab^2+b^3)c+abc^2+ac^3+bc^3)}{(a+c)(b+c)(a^2+bc)(b^2+ac)}\geq0$

Comment: Please don't make superficial tag edits to the question (you've answered) in order gain tag points, nor to bump a question you answered more than a year and a half-ago.  Editing a question in order to get more votes on tags that did not, and don't, apply, is gaming the system. And repeated bumping of the question, via superficial edits, as you tried in April, and today, is also gaming.